# How can I make a contour plot from two lists?

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation

I have a matrix called sigmaelement

```
sigmaelement[[All, a, e]] = Ce.Belement[[All, All, e]].ELd[[All, e]];
```

`sigmaelement[[1,All,1]]` will have values I want to contour plot

I also have a matrix called

```
coordinates = {{x1,y1}, {x2,y2}}
```

When I look at the documentation, I find an example like

```
ListContourPlot[Table[Sin[i + j^2], {i, 0, 3, 0.1}, {j, 0, 3, 0.1}]]
```

but in my case, instead of `Sin[i+j^2]`, I want to use `sigmaelement[[1, All, 1]]`. and instead of `i` and `j`, I want to use `coordinates`.

Could you tell me what could be the answer?

Comment: Is `Length @ sigmaelement[[1, All, 1]]` the same as `Length @ coordinates`? I.e. are `coordinates` ordered to match `sigmaelement[[1, All, 1]]`?

Comment: Yes @MariusLadegårdMeyer they match

Comment: `ListContourPlot[
 Transpose@{coordinates, sigmaElement[[1,All,1]]} /. {{x_, y_}, z_} -> {x, y, z}]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to get your data into the form

```
{{x1, y1, sigmaelement1},{x2, y2, sigmaelement2}, ..., {xn, yn, sigmaelementn}}
```

`ListContourPlot` doesn't require the coordinates to be a rectangular array, but it gives better results when they are.

Since you don't supply any usable data, I will contrive some.

```
coordinates = Catenate @ CoordinateBoundsArray[{{0, 9}, {0, 9}}];
coordinates // Short
```

> `{{0, 0}, {0, 1}, {0, 2}, {0, 3}, <<92>>, {9, 6}, {9, 7}, {9, 8}, {9, 9}}`

```
SeedRandom[42]; sigmaelement = RandomReal[1., 100];
sigmaelement // Short
```

> `{0.425905, <<98>>, 0.0792812}`

Now I put the two lists, `coordinates` and `sigmaelement` into the form needed. I show two ways to do this.

```
data = MapThread[{#1[[1]], #1[[2]], #2} &, {coordinates, sigmaelement}];
data = {#1[[1]], #1[[2]], #2} & @@@ Transpose[{coordinates, sigmaelement}];
data // Short
```

> `{{0, 0, 0.425905}, <<98>>, {9, 9, 0.0792812}}`

Now the contour plot is very simple.

```
ListContourPlot[data]
```

[image: plot]

Comment: Thank you for your answer @m_goldberg. I understand your first way which is              data = MapThread[{#1[[1]], #1[[2]], #2} &, {coordinates, sigmaelement}];  but the problem is my x coordinate matrix dimension is 1x231x2 in fact I have 1 row 231 columns but since I have two elements third dimension is for 2 elements. I have 231 x coordinates for element 1 and other 231 x coordinates for element 2 ; similarly y coordinate matrix dimension is 1x231x2 and my sigmaelement matrix dimension is 3x231x2; here I want to use only first row 1x231x2. How could we arrange MapThread ?

Comment: @m_goldberg, I was analyzing your answer. I found your answer was so amazing and enjoyable!

Answer (score 4):

The second form of [ListContourPlot](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListContourPlot.html) expects a list of triplets: `{{x1,y1,f1},{x2,y2,f2},...}`. So your question is how to combine two lists `coordinates` and `values=sigmaelement[[1,All,1]]` in one list of correct form. There are many possible ways to do this.

Straightforward using `Table`:

```
tab[coordinates_, values_]:= Table[{coordinates[[i, 1]], coordinates[[i, 2]], values[[i]]}, {i, 1, Length@values}]
```

Using `Transpose` and mapping transformation function over the list:

```
map[coordinates_, values_]:={#1[[1, 1]], #1[[1, 2]], #[[2]]} & /@Transpose@{coordinates, values};
```

or using replacement rules (in my opinion this one is the most clear):

```
repl[coordinates_, values_]:=Transpose@{coordinates, values} /. {{x_, y_}, z_} -> {x, y, z}
```

or using `Flatten` (thanks to @corey979):

```
cor1[coordinates_, values_]:=Flatten[#, 1] & /@ Transpose[{coordinates, values}]
```

or using `ArrayReshape` (thanks to @corey979 again):

```
cor2[coordinates_, values_]:=ArrayReshape[Transpose@{coordinates, values}, {Length@values, 3}]
```

Using `MapThread` to avoid transposing

```
mapTr[coordinates_, values_]:=MapThread[#1~Join~{#2} &, {coordinates, values}]
```

Since we have many options let's run quick performance benchmark for $10^6$ elements. I added two other functions from @m_goldberg's answer.

```
genData[n_] := {RandomReal[1.0, {n, 2}], RandomReal[1.0, {n}]};
funList = {tab, map, mapTr, cor1, cor2, repl, mg1, mg2};    
timingFun[funList_, {c_, v_}] := First@AbsoluteTiming[#[c, v]] & /@ funList;
timings = timingFun[funList, genData[10^6]]    
BarChart[{timings}, ChartElementFunction -> "GlassRectangle", 
 ChartStyle -> "Pastel", ChartLabels -> funList]
```

[image]

So `Table` is a clear winner.

Comment: Also `Flatten[#, 1] & /@ Transpose[{coordinates, values}]` and `ArrayReshape[Transpose@{coordinates, values}, {Length@values, 3}]`.

Comment: I don't know if this applies to the OP or not, but if the coordinates form a rectangular grid, then it is better to use the `ListContourPlot[array]` form, as you get better interpolation.